# How to split string using hyphen in SQL data table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following ID in my database:

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
('1111-DXA-'),
('111-BCN-C1'),
('111-DEL-C1'),
('111JK1004JK1-000000/002'),
('11111-GOT-17C5'),
('11111-JHB-0' );


SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE( 
            SUBSTRING(
                    SUBSTRING(REVERSE([SomeCol]) , CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE([SomeCol]))  +1 , LEN([SomeCol]) )
                     , 1 , CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(REVERSE([SomeCol]) , CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE([SomeCol]))  +1 , LEN([SomeCol]) ) ) -1
                    )
                )))
FROM @YourTable
```

Exception :Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Can you pls suggest me on this.

Comment: It's because on the fourth row you only have one hyphen and that's messing up with your substring function. Do all strings have exactly two hyphens? Which part of string are you trying to capture?

Comment: The fourth value only has a single hyphen. Is that possibly the cause?

Comment: DXA,BCN,DEL,JK1,GOT,JHB ; I need to process fourth row also. There will be single hyphen and also two hyphens. Can you pls suggest any other alternative.